# How to POST unanswered radio button questions as NULL values into MySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, null, radio-button

I am using the script below to store values for dynamically created forms in to a MySQL database.  Users can return to the form after it is saved to update information.

The application uses radio button form elements, which are only sent through POST if they are answered.  The default value in the MySQL database is set to NULL.  So if a question is not answered, it remains NULL, which is great.

However, I also use jQuery to allow certain form elements to be reset (i.e. radio buttons can be cleared).

If a user answers a radio button question, saves the form, returns at a later date, and clears the radio button question, the value never gets set back to NULL in my database.

Any ideas on how I can make this happen?

```
<?php 

require_once('../../includes/connect.php');

$org_id = $_SESSION['ORG_ID'];
$user_id = $_SESSION['USER_ID'];

$dbh = get_org_dbh($org_id);

$sql = "UPDATE health_forms SET ";
$values = array();

foreach ($_POST as $field => $value){

    $sql .= "$field=?, ";
    array_push($values, $value);

}

$sql = rtrim($sql,", ");   
$sql .= " WHERE id=?;\n";
array_push($values, $user_id);

try { 

    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute($values);
}  

header("location: ../index.php?i=completed");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about *rewriting* previously saved values with NULLs, you have but only choice - select whole row first, compare it with POSTED values and set absent fields to nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Set the default to NULL for whatever column you are nullifying, then just skip it in your SQL request. That has worked wonderfully for me. You can do this easily from PHPmyadmin.

Comment: Hi Adam, the default is already set to NULL in my database for all columns.  For questions that are never answered in the first place, these remain null.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once('../../includes/connect.php');

$org_id = $_SESSION['ORG_ID'];
$user_id = $_SESSION['USER_ID'];

$dbh = get_org_dbh($org_id);

$sql = "UPDATE health_forms SET ";
$values = array();

$table_fields = array('name', 'status', 'etc');

foreach ($table_fields as $field){
    if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
        $sql .= "$field=?, ";
        array_push($values, $_POST[$field]);
    } else {
        $sql .= "$field=NULL, ";
    }

}

$sql = rtrim($sql,", ");   
$sql .= " WHERE id=?;\n";
array_push($values, $user_id);

try { 

    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute($values);
}

header("location: ../index.php?i=completed");
```

Define your database table fields in the `$table_fileds` array, and you are ready.